# LIMITAR A DOIS CARACTERES DE SAÍDA COM REGEX - POSTGRESQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql

Eu tenho a consulta abaixo que me retorna apenas os valores numéricos do meu campo de string, eu queria limitá-lo a dois caracteres de saída.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT NULLIF(regexp_replace(temperature, '\D','','g'), '')::numeric AS "Temperature"
from tbl_temperature_hosts
where temperature like '%Core 0%' limit 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
6601205698
```

**EXPECTED OUTCOME**

```
66
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente seu problema tente:

```
SELECT LEFT(NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE(temperature, '\D','','g'), ''), 2)::numeric AS "Temperature"
FROM tbl_temperature_hosts
WHERE temperature LIKE '%Core 0%' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!